# Third segment / last_segment "success" not working?

Tags: segments, switchee

I am attempting to display a message when the last segment equals "success"... I've done this many times before and for some reason I am having some trouble. I need an extra eye perhaps?

Below is my code. The url upon submission redirects and looks like this: http://site.dev/events/event_submission/success/

However, the third segment isn't being read by EE because {last_segment} equals "event_submission" and {segment_3} parses blank.

```
{exp:switchee variable="global:member_group" parse_tags="yes" parse="inward"}

    {case value="1"}
        {if last_segment == 'success'}
            Your event has been submitted. You will receive notification when your event has been approved or rejected. You can <a href="{path=logout}">logout</a> now or <a href="{site_url}events/event_submission">click here</a> to create another event.
        {if:else}
        {exp:channel:form channel="events_submitted" id="publishForm" return="events/event_submission/success" json="yes" include_jquery="no"}
            "Just to test: {last_segment} {segment_3}"
            <p>Welcome back, <strong>{screen_name}</strong>!</p>
```

I am sure I am just having a coding block but I cannot get it going... any tips?

Comment: Do you have structure or freebie addons installed at all?

Comment: I do have Structure installed but it doesn't manage this channel...

Comment: My only thought is that you may have freebie installed, which is a useful extension for structure. By default it makes success|error|preview in the segments "EE will act as if these segments aren’t in the URI at all". Check to see if you have this installed, in which case use {freebie_3} to catch that segment (Freebie will work regardless of the channel used for structure). Or you could try changing "success" segment to something else like "thankyou".

Comment: You were right. We had Freebie installed for a feature we never used. But it was the culprit. Thanks! Make an answer and Ill mark it correct.

Comment: Good to hear. Just another one of those things to watch out for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My only thought is that you may have freebie installed, which is a useful extension for structure. By default it makes success|error|preview in the segments "EE will act as if these segments aren’t in the URI at all". Check to see if you have this installed, in which case use {freebie_3} to catch that segment (Freebie will work regardless of the channel used for structure). Or you could try changing "success" segment to something else like "thankyou".